# What can I use in PostgreSQL which will be similar to dtsx packages in SQL?

Tags: postgresql, package

I am new to PostgreSQL database. I have to transform my database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.
In SQL we are using SSIS dtsx packages.
As we are using SSIS for importing and exporting data to and from sql server so I need to know about what is the equivalent of ssis in postgresql?
What can I used similar to this SSIS in PostgreSQL? 
Please suggest me appropriate answer.

Comment: For those that are only experienced with Postgres: what does this `dtsx` thing do? Are those packages something similar as Oracle packages? (e.g. modules for stored procedures)? What exactly is the problem you need to solve with that?

Comment: According to me, we are using dtsx packages in SQL to perform the all ETL process by running this packages. The similar I want to know in PostgreSQL database.

Comment: I have tried to find out but as I am new to this database. Taking time to get result

Comment: for a hepl u can refer this- [link]https://www.devart.com/ssis/postgresql.html